# "Who hasn't slept in three days" vs "Who didn't sleep in three days"

Tags: grammaticality, present-perfect, past-simple

I was reading a comic book when I saw this sentence:

> Who hasn't slept in three days.

I admit it's a little bit difficult to get the hang of this verb tense. My mind just sees the usage of `Present Perfect` when I don't mention the time, but `Three days` doesn't express time?

Complete sentence:

> Who hasn't slept in three days, who got his arm broken and hasn't had
>   it looked at yet, who is now hiking through the tropical jungle in his
>   full-body long Johns and booties.

Dialogue:

[image: Picture]:

Comment: It looks correct to me, but it's hard to be sure because it's not a complete sentence.  Yes, *three days* expresses a span of time.  It's saying that the person has not slept during the span of the last three days.

Comment: The sentence is just it, after he says `Who got his arm broken!`. Is possible to use simple past?

Comment: We can probably guess, but it'd be helpful to give us more context. It's not a sentence, it's (probably) a relative clause, and it presumably only works as an utterance because you have the preceding context in the comic you haven't shared with us.

Comment: I'll updated it

Comment: There wasn't anything *before* this?

Comment: Not exactly, there was another balloon, wait..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As snailboat has hinted in comments, you need to look *backward*, not forward. The key information comes **before** the phrase in question. You need to look at the [whole dialogue](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/New_Avengers_Vol_1_6):

> **Spider-Man**: Anyone want to carry me?
>   **Luke Cage**: Don't you have the proportionate strength of a spider?
>   **Spider-Man**: Who hasn't slept in three days, who got his arm broken and hasn't had it looked at yet, who is now hiking though the tropical jungle in his full-body long johns and booties.

Essentially, Mr. Parker is answering the question from Luke, saying (the part in italics is elided):

> *Yes, I have the strength of a spider – of a spider* who hasn't slept in three days, who got his arm broken...

We could reword it to something like this:

> Yes, I have the strength of a spider. However, this spider hasn't slept in three days, and he got his arm broken...

Hopefully, that use of "in three days" looks more normal. In conversation, though, sometimes phrases get clipped, and the speaker essentially begins mid-sentence.

Comment: **in three days** sounds very odd to me. But **for three days** seems fine to me. Do you prefer **for** or **in** there?

Comment: @Man_From_India - Either one is fine. NOAD defines _in_ as "expressing a period of time during which a situation remains the case". So we can say, "I haven't exercised in months," or, "I haven't slept in three days." But _for_ would work just as well.

Comment: Actually why it seems odd to me is not for **in**, it is because of the verb. For example : *he studied English for two years* (using **in** there is incorrect). In our case I interpreted the action to be complete that the verb denotes. But again it's present perfect, and that means it's not the completed action, so I might be wrong in my assumption.

Comment: @Man_From_India - Great points! The words _for_ and _in_ are not always interchangeable in this context; moreover, I'd have a hard time explaining when they could be interchangeable, and when they shouldn't be. But "I haven't slept in three days" doesn't sound strange to me – especially if the speaker is very tired and has a broken arm.

Comment: @Man_From_India I think if you posted a question about using *for* and *in* in this example, it'd make a great post :-)

Comment: Hi @J.R. now I'm getting it, I use this site for my studies [Present Perfect](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/presentperfect.html) and reading it right now I left escape this **USE 2 Duration From the Past Until Now**. Am I right? Taking advance of sentence used by Man_From_India, he says `he studied English for two years` that's express something continuous, then, `he's studied English for two years`. Is also right?

Comment: @TM - You're right. `He studied English for two years` means he studied in the past, but we don't know when. `He has studied English for two years` means he is two years into his studies, but the studies are most likely ongoing.

Answer (score 0):

> **Who hasn't slept in three days.** *( statement )*
>
> The crew was tired and irritable after finishing their dinner, and then David entered the room. **Who hasn't slept in three days...**

is a phrase referring to *someone* saying they have not slept in three days.

> **Who hasn't slept in three days?** *( question )*

is asking a question, which might be real or rhetorical very much depending on context, about sleeping the past three days.

> Captain: **Who hasn't slept in three days?**
>   Sailor: David hasn't, he's been on watch for 72 hours straight.
>   Captain: Relieve his post immediately.
>
> Captain: We should all be rested and relaxed.
>   I mean, **who hasn't slept in** *the* **three days** *we've been here*?
>   It's been all sun and fun.

**Three days** merely adds additional context around when in the past things began.